# Pytube library - Receiving "pytube.exceptions.RegexMatchError: regex pattern" error when attempting to access video data

Tags: python, python-3.x

When attempting to access data such as the "title" of a Youtube video using the pytube API library, I am receiving the following error

> pytube.exceptions.RegexMatchError: regex pattern (yt.akamaized.net/)\s*\|\|\s*.*?\s*c\s*&&\s*d.set([^,]+\s*,\s*(?P[a-zA-Z0-9$]+)() had zero matches

Here is the code that I am using which is providing the error above.

```
import sys  
import pytube

link = input('Enter url: ') # url is: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KSbj-cFtFPA
yt = pytube.YouTube(link)
print(yt.title)

sys.exit()
```

Might anyone know how to resolve this error? I have done some on-line searching, the answers provided were not definitive and did not work when I try.

Note: I tried to uninstall pytube and re-install it but that did not fix the issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a bug in pytube, so reinstall it using this command.

```
pip install git+https://github.com/nficano/pytube.git

#####################################################

import sys
import pytube

link = input('Enter url: ') # url is: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KSbjcFtFPA
yt = pytube.YouTube(link)
print(yt.title)

**OUTPUT** Sanford and Son S02E02

sys.exit()
```

Here is some additional information on this bug: https://github.com/nficano/pytube/issues/333

This is a follow-up response to the question.  I added some error handling based on the documentation to tell you what is occurring.

```
- Video 1 in the list will throw an extraction error. because the video has been removed from YouTube

- Video 2 in the list will throw an unavailable error. because the video does not exist on YouTube

- Video 3 in the list will display the correct title info, because the video exists on YouTube.

video_lists = ['https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KSbjcFtFPA',
           'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MEEJOZkmIxvU',
           'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MEEJOZkmIxU'
           ]

for video in video_lists:

  try:
    yt = pytube.YouTube(video)
    print (yt.title)

  #################################################################
  # This one should catch - pytube.exceptions.RegexMatchError:
  # regex pattern ((?:v=|\/)([0-9A-Za-z_-]{11}).*) had zero matches
  #################################################################
  except pytube.exceptions.RegexMatchError:
    print('The Regex pattern did not return any matches for the video: {}'.format(video))

  except pytube.exceptions.ExtractError:
    print ('An extraction error occurred for the video: {}'.format(video))

  except pytube.exceptions.VideoUnavailable:
    print('The following video is unavailable: {}'.format(video))

**OUTPUTS**
An extraction occurred for the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KSbjcFtFPA

The following video is unavailable: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MEEJOZkmIxvU

Love of my life & Bohemian Rhapsody - 1080 HD
```

**SPECIAL NOTE**

The error in question has been linked to the file cipher.py for pytube. Please check this file to ensure that the section of code below matches yours:

```
def get_initial_function_name(js):
"""Extract the name of the function responsible for computing the signature.

:param str js:
    The contents of the base.js asset file.

"""
# c&&d.set("signature", EE(c));
pattern = r'\bc\s*&&\s*d\.set\([^,]+\s*,\s*\([^)]*\)\s*\(\s*(?P<sig>[a-zA-Z0-9$]+)\('
logger.debug('finding initial function name')
return regex_search(pattern, js, group=1)
```

Comment: I reinstalled pytube as you suggested using "pip install git+https://github.com/nficano/pytube.git" and re-ran the above script but I got the same error unfortunately. I am using python 3.7, not sure if this is the cause. Which version of Python are you using?

Comment: I'm using python 3.6.

Comment: I have pytube 9.3.5 installed.

Comment: I tried  python 3.6 with  pytube 9.3.5 installed and it still receiving the same error.

Comment: I did yes the other day; however, it does not print the title as indicated in your output. It only catches the error and prints the messages you defined above.

Comment: So when you run my follow-up code, you don't get 3 answers?

Comment: I get this: An extraction error occurred for the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KSbjcFtFPA
The following video is unavailable: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MEEJOZkmIxvU
An extraction error occurred for the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MEEJOZkmIxU

Comment: I was expecting the title as the last message as indicated in your example, "Love of my life & Bohemian Rhapsody - 1080 HD"

Comment: I just ran the code again and I get the correct values.   I rechecked my pytube module. pip3 list shows that I have 9.3.6 installed on Python 3.6.5

Comment: I will try that version of python and pytube and get back to you.

Comment: installed Python 9.6.5 & Pytube 9.3.6. This is what I get:   An extraction error occurred for the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KSbjcFtFPA
The following video is unavailable: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MEEJOZkmIxvU
An extraction error occurred for the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MEEJOZkmIxU. No title on the output.

Comment: I just added another exception handler to my answer.  If that doesn't work, then we need to do some more research, because something on your system is likely contributing to this issue.

Comment: You're welcome.  Sometimes it takes a village to solve a problem.  Good luck with the rest of your coding project.

Answer (score 0):

@ Victor S: try install pytube and pytubetemp, make sure both are 9.4.0. do not change import, re-run your code.

Comment: Life is complex already provided me the answer. Thanks anyway.