# pytube error - get_ytplayer_config: could not find match for config_patterns when passing a list of URLS

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup, youtube, pytube

I'm trying to use pytube to pass a list of URLs from one YouTube channel in order to pull certain bits of YouTube metadata for analysis. Here's the code I'm using:

```
import pandas as pd
from pytube import YouTube

url_list = pd.read_csv("data.csv").values
```

'data.csv' is just a single column containing nothing but about 2000 URLs in the YouTube format. None of the videos are privated, as far as I'm aware.

```
data = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['title', 'views', 'description', 'length', 'rating'])

lists = []

for url in url_list:
  try:
    urls = str(url)
    yt = YouTube(urls)
    lists.append([yt.title, yt.views, yt.description, yt.length, yt.rating])
  except Exception as e:
    lists.append(['NA', 'NA' , 'NA', 'NA', 'NA'])
    print(e)
```

The problem here is that it's a toss-up whether or not YouTube will return the values I need! The URLs that work are appended to the list nicely, but if not:

```
RegexMatchError: get_ytplayer_config: could not find match for config_patterns
```

and eventually, I get this error too for every URL after the first time this error occurs:

```
HTTP Error 429: Too Many Requests
```

I've tried using BeautifulSoup but keep getting some sort of frustrating 'assets' error as well as this:

```
MissingSchema: Invalid URL 'u': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http://u?
```

If anyone could suggest any way to fix this or alternatives, that would be brilliant, because I've been scratching my head trying to figure out a solution.

Comment: There was a bug reported. See [this previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54032828/4543452) with a error handling.

Answer (score 1):

This error
(RegexMatchError: get_ytplayer_config: could not find match for config_patterns) is due to Pytube known issue.

Try to update request.py

https://github.com/nficano/pytube/issues/614
https://github.com/nficano/pytube/issues/614#issuecomment-724326141

OR
Better install recently fixed version of PyTube pkg
https://github.com/nficano/pytube/issues/815#issuecomment-725747111

After installing updated pkg this issue resolved for me.