# RegexMatchError with pytube

Tags: python, pysimplegui, pytube

I have this code, and i cant download whit this interface, why?
When I try to run this code, just nothing happens

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\gerso\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\layout.py", line 17, in <module>
    yt = YouTube('link')
  File "C:\Users\gerso\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 77, in __init__
    self.video_id = extract.video_id(url)
  File "C:\Users\gerso\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pytube\extract.py", line 80, in video_id
    return regex_search(r"(?:v=|\/)([0-9A-Za-z_-]{11}).*", url, group=1)
  File "C:\Users\gerso\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pytube\helpers.py", line 34, in regex_search
    raise RegexMatchError(caller="regex_search", pattern=pattern)
pytube.exceptions.RegexMatchError: regex_search: could not find match for (?:v=|\/)([0-9A-Za-z_-]{11}).*
```

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg
from pytube import YouTube

sg.theme('DarkAmber')   # Add a touch of color
# All the stuff inside your window.
layout = [  [sg.Text('Link:'), sg.Input(key='link')],
            [sg.Text('Diretório'), sg.Input()],
            [sg.Button('Download'), sg.Button('Cancel')]]

# Create the Window
window = sg.Window('Window Title', layout)
# Event Loop to process "events" and get the "values" of the inputs
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    # se o usuario apertar download
    if event == 'Download':
        yt = YouTube('link')
        video = yt.streams.get_highest_resolution()
        video.download()

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Cancel': # Se o usuário fechar a janela ou cancelar
        break


window.close()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pytube library - Receiving "pytube.exceptions.RegexMatchError: regex pattern" error when attempting to access video data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54028675/pytube-library-receiving-pytube-exceptions-regexmatcherror-regex-pattern-er)

Comment: dosen't work for mi

Comment: Wrong code `yt = YouTube('link')`, maybe `yt = YouTube(values['link'])` !

Answer (score 0):

**try upgrade to latest version so upgrade to the latest version like this**

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pytube
```

**or on windows**

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pytube
```

**and you can also try this driver code**

```
import sys # import sys 
import pytube


link = 'put link here'
yt = pytube.YouTube(link)
stream = yt.streams.get_highest_resolution()
finished = stream.download()
print('Download is complete')

sys.exit()
```