# RegexMatchError: get_throttling_function_name: could not find match for multiple error for pytube

Tags: python, pytube, openai-whisper

cipher.py

```
function_pattern = [
    r'a\.[a-zA-Z]\s*&&\s*\([a-z]\s*=\s*a\.get\("n"\)\)\s*&&\s*'
    r'\([a-z]\s*=\s*([a-zA-Z0-9$]+)(\[\d+\])?\([a-z]\)',
]
```

```
    RegexMatchError: get_throttling_function_name: could not find match for multiple
    Traceback:
    File "C:\Users\komal.kekare\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\streamlit\runtime\scriptrunner\script_runner.py", line 552, in _run_script
        exec(code, module.__dict__)
    File "C:\Users\komal.kekare\Projects\GenAI-youtube-video-content-chat\app.py", line 96, in <module>
        main()
    File "C:\Users\komal.kekare\Projects\GenAI-youtube-video-content-chat\app.py", line 83, in main
        url_raw_text = youtube_gen.get_url_text(url_link)
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "C:\Users\komal.kekare\Projects\GenAI-youtube-video-content-chat\youtube_gen.py", line 66, in get_url_text
        transcription = video_to_audio(url_link)
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "C:\Users\komal.kekare\Projects\GenAI-youtube-video-content-chat\youtube_gen.py", line 48, in video_to_audio
        audio = video.streams.filter(only_audio=True).first()
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "C:\Users\komal.kekare\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 296, in streams
        return StreamQuery(self.fmt_streams)
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "C:\Users\komal.kekare\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 188, in fmt_streams
        extract.apply_signature(stream_manifest, self.vid_info, self.js)
    File "C:\Users\komal.kekare\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pytube\extract.py", line 409, in apply_signature
        cipher = Cipher(js=js)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "C:\Users\komal.kekare\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pytube\cipher.py", line 43, in __init__
        self.throttling_plan = get_throttling_plan(js)
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "C:\Users\komal.kekare\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pytube\cipher.py", line 407, in get_throttling_plan
        raw_code = get_throttling_function_code(js)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "C:\Users\komal.kekare\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pytube\cipher.py", line 313, in get_throttling_function_code
        name = re.escape(get_throttling_function_name(js))
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "C:\Users\komal.kekare\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pytube\cipher.py", line 298, in get_throttling_function_name
        raise RegexMatchError(
```

Comment: Based on this answer you may need to check your Python and Pytube versions and possibly reinstall it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54028675/pytube-library-receiving-pytube-exceptions-regexmatcherror-regex-pattern-er